# How to create replica set in mongodb compass mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ecommerce-shop?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma

I am using Next js and try to create Ecommerce-app using mongodb and Prisma. i have create my add-product page.

```
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export const metadata = {
    title: 'Add Product Page',
    description: 'Adding Product using server actions ',
  }
export  const addProduct=async(formData)=>{
    "use server"
    const name=formData.get("name");
    const price=Number(formData.get("price")||0) ;
    const description=formData.get("description");
    const imageUrl=formData.get("imageUrl");
    console.log(name+" "+price+" "+description+" "+imageUrl+" ")
    if(!name || !price || !description || !imageUrl){
      throw new Error("Missing Required FIelds")
    }
    await prisma.product.create({
      data:{name,price,description,imageUrl}
    })
    redirect("/")
}
const AddProduct = () => {
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center'>
        <h1 className='font-bold mb-3 text-lg md:text-2xl'>Add Product</h1>
        <form action={addProduct} className='w-1/2 m-2'>
       <div className='flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-center items-center w-full mb-2'> 
        <label className='text-lg font-bold md:w-1/3 w-auto mb-2 md:mb-0 mr-0 md:mr-1 '>Product Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Product Name" name="name" className="input input-bordered w-full" required  />
       </div>
       <div className='flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-center items-center w-full mb-2'> 
        <label className='text-lg font-bold md:w-1/3 w-auto mb-2 md:mb-0 mr-0 md:mr-1'>Description</label>
        <textarea type="text" placeholder="Enter Product Description" name="description" className="textarea textarea-bordered w-full" required  />
       </div>
       <div className='flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-center items-center w-full mb-2'> 
        <label className='text-lg font-bold md:w-1/3 w-auto mb-2 md:mb-0 mr-0 md:mr-1'>Product Image</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Image Url" name="imageUrl" className="input input-bordered w-full" required  />
       </div>
       <div className='flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-center items-center w-full mb-2'> 
        <label className='text-lg font-bold md:w-1/3 w-auto mb-2 md:mb-0 mr-0 md:mr-1'>Product Price</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Product Price" name="price" className="input input-bordered w-full" required  />
       </div>
       <button className="btn btn-accent">Submit</button>
       </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AddProduct
```

Here is my .env file

```
DATABASE_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/ecommerce-shop?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Here is the schema.prisma

```
datasource db {
 provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model Product {
  id          String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  description String
  imageUrl    String
  name        String
  price       Int
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt

  @@map("products")
  }
```

whenever i try to add the product using server actions i face the Error.

```
Error: 
Invalid `prisma.product.create()` invocation:


Prisma needs to perform transactions, which requires your MongoDB server to be run as a replica set. https://pris.ly/d/mongodb-replica-set
```

kindly canone tell me the solution how can i create the mongodb-replica-set using mongodb-compass on my local machine. i have searched and tried their solutions but couldn't get rid of this problem

Comment: `i have searched and tried their solutions`  What solutions did you try?  Perhaps https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/?

Comment: Please provide more information on how you deploy the MongoDB and what solution you had tried. MongoDB Compass is just a GUI.

With the limited information; You could either
1. Follow Joe Link
2. Deploy a MongoDB using MongoDB Atlas which is repl set by default

Comment: As per your instructions i have deployed my db to mongodb atlas when i try to npx prisma db push i got error Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MongoDB database "next-ecommerce" at "cluster0.r5pgykv.mongodb.net"
Error: MongoDB error
Kind: An error occurred during DNS resolution: proto error: io error: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. (os error 10051), labels: {}
   0: schema_core::commands::schema_push::Calculate `from`
             at schema-engine\core\src\commands\schema_push.rs:29

Comment: as i posted the above problem which i was facing in the mongo db atlas has been resolved after installing the cloudflare warp vpn from their given link. https://developers.cloudflare.com/warp-client/get-started/windows/     i don't know why my mongodb atlas not connecting and why it is connected after installing this warp vpn. if anyone have answer then kindly enlighten me